# Android app closes itself when adding an image

Tags: android, imageview

Since I added my first image (png, in folder drawable) on Android Studio, my app closes itself at the launch when I launch it on my phone.
There is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/androidparty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="@string/happy_birthday_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="@string/signature_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I delete the ImageView it's working.
I tried to move the image from drawable to drawable-v24 and to replace
app:srcCompat="@drawable/androidparty"
by
android:src="@drawable/androidparty"

This is one of the first exercice from Developer Android, so I have the solution code on gitHub. I run it, but the app still fail at launch.

The logcat :

```
2022-09-28 20:48:18.465 16129-16129/com.example.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.happybirthday, PID: 16129
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 118054956 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 111MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3730)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Could you help please ?

Thank you

// edit : I reduced the image from 450Ko to 86Ko, but it was still not working.
Finally I add the following code in the manifest and it works

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"    
android:largeHeap="true"`
```

Comment: can you check what is your png size?

Comment: The Image you are using is very large reduce its size